# prevent grid from overflowing inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm not sure why the images are taking up so much space and causing an overflow. If the imgs were replaced with a text it looks fine.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  $("#grid").append(`
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
    </div>
  `);  
}
```

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  height: 20%;
}
.upper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;

}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class='upper'>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is:

- `height: 100%` on `#grid` combined with `border: 1px` and not using `box-sizing: border-box`
- the classical *inline* white space on `item` and `image`

The fix:

- add `box-sizing: border-box` on `#grid` (or use calc, `height: calc(100% - 2px)`)
- remove `inline-block` on `item` and add `display: block` on `img`

*For the centering of the image, and as being a block, I also added `margin: 0 auto` and removed `text-align: center` as it has no effect anymore.*

Stack snippet

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  $("#grid").append(`
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
    </div>
  `);  
}
```

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  height: 20%;
}
.upper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;                  /*  added  */
}

.item {
  /*display: inline-block;                     removed  */
  /*text-align: center;                        removed  */

  min-height: 0;                           /*  Firefox fix  */
}

img {
  display: block;                          /*  added  */
  margin: 0 auto;                          /*  added  */
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;           /*  might want this too  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class='upper'>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Vue and I'm not sure why it's completely ignoring the `max-height` I set. I'll have to keep dabbling it a bit.

Comment: @A.Lau If you follow up the styles Vue use/set you might find it, still, the answer I gave show the reason why the scroll appears. If you have a link to a working sample using Vue, I'll have a look.

Comment: I'll try making a public repo of the part where it's having this weird issue

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to make a card game, so I'd like the grids just to space them out evenly, while putting another div inside so it's as large as the image, while having some text on top (using `position: absolute`)

Comment: I've decided to open a new question since this one was a bit ambiguous and already has answers for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255747/css-nested-div-in-grid-does-not-respect-grid-sizes

Comment: @A.Lau As you said yourself in the first comment (before you edited it), my answer explains the real reason of the issue you have in the posted code, and still you choose to accept an answer that does not? ... I find that odd, don't you?

Comment: yeah I think it does help, so I'm going to change my approach, changed answer to yours.

Comment: @A.Lau Thanks .... I also made a comment at your new question, with a link, to show what it takes

Comment: I just realised this solution doesn't work on firefox

Comment: @A.Lau Will have a look later today

Comment: Dw, I asked another question and found that you need to add `min-height: 0`

Comment: @A.Lau That is correct, to make Firefox behave...just updated my answer with that. `min-height` defaults to `auto`, and prevents items to be smaller than its content, and in some case it need to be set to `0` allowing them to shrink and fit its parent

Answer (score 2):

You may use images as background, it will be easier to control and avoid overflow. Also don't forget the border in the height  calculation so you may add `box-sizing:border-box` :

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  $("#grid").append(`
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x350)">
     
    </div>
  `);
}
```

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  height: 20%;
}

.upper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class='upper'>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I generally don't want the overflow, which is hwy I'd like the img's height to be based on the grid.

Comment: ah right, using the img as the background, how could I forget, I'll give a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to shrink grid items which contain elements with intrinsic dimensions such as images - while retaining aspect ratio

```
img { object-fit: contain; }
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  $("#grid").append(`
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
    </div>
  `);  
}
```

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
  height: 20%;
}
.upper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class='upper'>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's quite the issue. I've opened another question that properly corresponds to my problem since this one was poorly worded. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47255747/6554121